# how to split left and right in two different speakers

Tags: signal

I have two self-powered speakers I want to split the signal into left and right, the way I currently have it is from RCA to 3.5 on each one, but that's not giving me stereo sound.

[image: Speaker]

Comment: Where does your signal come from. How do you connect the cables?

Comment: Can't find any info on the device - but it looks like it only has a single mono line out. You should consult the manual or contact the manufacturer; this is really a hardware support issue, not sound design.

Comment: @ghellquist I connect each speaker from RCA to 3.5mm the signal comes from my PC I'm using a Y cable splitter, I have two speakers each with RCA to 3.5mm (male) and from the PC a Y Splitter to Females

Comment: @Tetsujin this product is discontinued and the manufacturer does not offer support, can't I transform two mono lines into stereo? splitting each speaker into left and the other speaker into right?

Comment: @Romano It sounds to me you should connect a 3.5mm to your PC (which should have stereo out), then splitting the signal, then connect Left RCA to one speaker Line In and Right RCA to other speaker Line In. You will need one ready made cable: 3.5 mm stereo to 2x RCA.

Comment: @ghellquist I have this: https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00LM2Y2WC/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_search_asin_title?ie=UTF8&psc=1 and this:https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00LM0ZGK6/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_search_asin_title?ie=UTF8&psc=1 but it won't split the signal into left and right, do you have a link where I can find the piece that is missing to split the signal into left and right? Thanks!

Comment: @Romano Those should work. What contact on the PC do you use? Perhaps tell us which PC it is / If there is a sound card which it is. The cables should work if connect to the PC-s headphone output. Start by connection a headphone and make sure that your player program in the PC actually outputs stereo. Then one RCA per speaker.

Comment: @ghellquist I disconnected the white RCA cable on the right speaker and disconnected red RCA cable on the left speaker and the stereo sound is working! https://prnt.sc/110dlbx my question is: What I did is bad? will the speaker work at 100% still? I'm using this cable as I said in a previous comment https://www.amazon.com/dp/B00LM0ZGK6